# How to use GraphX with Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-graphx

I have a Spark Structured Streaming application which receives Kafka messages. For each such message it retrieves initial data from DB and performs calculations. I want to use GraphX (or GraphFrame) to build graph for each message and perform calculations. I understand how to do it with simple batch job, but how to use GraphX with Spark Streaming?